# How to do conditional replacement in R using "like" operator equivalent in SQL/SAS

Tags: conditional-statements

My data.frame has more than >100 observation. Below is just snapshot of it

```
   Variable
   BloodPressure
   HeartRate
   Residual
   BloodPressure1
   HeartRate1
   Residual1
   BloodPressure2
   HeartRate2
   Residual2
```

I want to get rid of numerical parts from above data.frame. My new output should look like

```
         Variable
         BloodPressure
         HeartRate
         Residual
         BloodPressure
         HeartRate
         Residual
         BloodPressure
         HeartRate
         Residual
```

Is there anyway I can use below condition in R like we use in SAS

```
 if variable like "%BloodPressure%" then new_variable = "BloodPressure"
```

or can I substring just character part from the variable and create new_variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to removed the digital numbers in the string, try the R function $ gsub $

```
> gsub("\\d+","","residual1")
[1] "residual"
```